# How to insert data into specific fields of mysql table from the first row in Java

Tags: java, mysql, insert, record

I have a table called Cast with these `fields : Id, CastName, CastImdbId`. This table already has many records. Now, I would like to add 3 new fields to this table which are `(gender, castBirthDate, castBirthPlace)`. The problem is that `"insert into"` add new data to the end of table (after the last record), but I need to add these data starting from the first record. Could someone please let me know if it is possible and how?

This is part of my code which has the problem:

```
 try{
     String query = "INSERT into Cast (gender, castBirthDate, castBirthPlace)" + "VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
     PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
     preparedStmt.setString (1, gender);
     preparedStmt.setString (2, dateOfBirth);
     preparedStmt.setString (3, placeOfBirth);
     preparedStmt.executeUpdate();

    }catch (Exception e){
        System.err.println("Got an exception!");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
    }
```

Comment: You don't want to insert complete new records. You want to `update` existing ones. Use the update syntax.

Comment: @juergend: Tnx, it worked :)

Comment: @monamona imDB still? O.o

Comment: @juergend: sorry, but do you know how could I use update for more than one field? (something like the code that I wrote in my question for insert statement.., but for update)

Comment: Look at the answers of your question to see how. If it still does not work, add to your question in detail why not.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `ALTER` statement on the table.

**Example**

```
ALTER TABLE Cast
ADD (gender varchar2(1), //Depending on "F" or "Female"
     castBirthDate Date, 
     castBirthPlace varchar2(50));
```

Then `UPDATE` the new fields. Which can be done in many ways. Avoid the `INSERT`.

`UPDATE` in `jdbc` is like this:

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("");
sql.append("UPDATE Cast ");
sql.append("SET gender = ?, ");
sql.append("castBirthDate = ?, ");
sql.append("castBirthPlace = ? ");
sql.append("WHERE actor_id = ?"); //Assuming...

PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStmt.setString (1, gender);
preparedStmt.setString (2, dateOfBirth);
preparedStmt.setString (3, placeOfBirth);
preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: sorry, where did u define the query? (in line 7), for instance in case of insert I had String query = "INSERT into Cast....

Comment: I concatenated the query in a StringBuilder, for me it is easier to read and also limits the memory taken(for just a String value) for larger queries

Comment: I did in this way and worked : String query = "update test set gender = ?, dateOfBirth = ?, placeOfBirth = ? where castImdbID = ?";.. however, tnx for your help :)

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to set those fields values to the existing records? Then you might want to `UPDATE` them.

As the name implies, an `INSERT` statement will add new rows at the end of the table.

`UPDATE` will modify the row or rows you specify, changing the values on the fields you specify.

```
UPDATE table SET column1='value1', column4='value2' WHERE column2='thisValue'
```

In your case, let's say you want to set 'Female' to "Halle Berry"

```
UPDATE Cast SET gender='Female' WHERE CastName='Halle Berry'
```

You should of course use IDs and references like `F` for 'female' and not the whole word.